# How to launch draw9patch and is it absolutely necessary to rescale pictures?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image, scale

I read on another forum that to launch draw9pad from your console, you have to do java -jar draw9patch.jar from the command prompt once youre in sdk. I did that but i still cannot launch the file. Is this tool absolutely necessary for your pictures to scale on different screens? I know that eclipse has these drawable folders that scale your pictures to different dpis or is that not what they do?
Console output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl8s3.jpg

File skd/tools :https://i.stack.imgur.com/iurXR.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read on another forum that to launch draw9pad from your console, you have to do java -jar draw9patch.jar from the command prompt once youre in sdk

Please use the `draw9patch` batch file or shell script found in the `tools/` directory of your SDK installation.

> I did that but i still cannot launch the file

First, that is because you did not type it in correctly, as you did not include the `.jar` extension.

Second, that JAR file is not in that directory. You can tell that by looking at the directory contents.

Instructions for running **`draw9patch`** can be found in [the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html).

> Is this tool absolutely necessary for your pictures to scale on different screens?

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch):

> A NinePatchDrawable graphic is a stretchable bitmap image, which Android will automatically resize to accommodate the contents of the View in which you have placed it as the background.

Scaling for different *screens* is not really the role of a nine-patch PNG file. Scaling for different *content* is. A nine-patch is used as the background for widgets like `Button`, `EditText`, and the like.

Comment: Thx i fixed the extensions and the directory problem(cd tools) Im still getting the error though. http://imgur.com/I7BDzmD For your second comment i see the draw9patch as a batch file in the tools directory

Comment: @committedandroider: I do not know why you are getting that message. When you run the `draw9patch.bat` (or `draw9patch.cmd`) file, such as by double-clicking on it in Windows Explorer, what happens?

Comment: the batch file? it opens some console like figure then closes right away

Comment: @committedandroider: OK, it is probably suffering from the same problem you are seeing at the command line. The only thing I can think of is if you installed the Android SDK as Administrator or something, and Windows is preventing you from running the JAR as a result, but that's just a guess.

Comment: i did install the android sdk as an admin. Is there any way i can still use the application though?

Comment: @committedandroider: You'll need to figure out a way to run that batch file as Administrator or something. I haven't used Windows significantly in several years, so I do not remember the details.

Comment: @committedandroider: Sorry, again, I am not a Windows guy, so I do not know what the problem might be.

Comment: thx for your help. I just ask another question on this when 90 minutes passes

Comment: Keep in mind that, if you use a 9 patch for providing rounded corners (such as a speech baloon), the roundings will look different (smaller on higher resolution screens), So, you'll have to make a different version for each resolution you'll support.

Answer (score 15):

To answer the first question for a Mac OS or Linux user, simply type `sh draw9patch` to launch the editor. CommonsWare already answered the second question.